# Failed to evaluate expression '#oauth2.throwOnError(#oauth2.hasRole('USER'))

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

i start a new project with spring-boot and oauth. I try to secure some url of my project.

Here my Httpsecurty config:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/test")
                .access("#oauth2.hasRole('USER')")
```

and i have this configuration too for my clientdetailsserviceconfigurer:

```
    clients.inMemory()
        .withClient("xxxxx")
        .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
        .authorities("USER")
        .scopes("read")
        .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
        .secret("sssss")
```

I registred an user with the role "USER" and i received an access_token from the server. But when i try to access the /test/ url with this token, i got this execption

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression '#oauth2.throwOnError(#oauth2.hasRole('USER'))'
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:13)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:34)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:18)
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:62)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)
```

And when i try it without the #oauth2 argument:

```
.access("hasRole('USER')")
```

, i got:

```
type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]
```

has someone any ideas?
Thanks
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I know the issue is very old, But fortunately the solution `.access("hasRole('USER')")` helped me. Well thanks for the help.

But for others (learning spring security) let me share my knowledge on the issue, It seems like the user with which you're trying to login doesn't have access to that role, So check your db `(USER_ROLE)` if that user has that role associated. Because in my scenario I was checking for Admin role and when I tried to login with the non-admin user the same error `'Access Denied'` appeared for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `WebExpressionVoter`'s `expressionHandler` to be an instance of `OAuth2WebSecurityExpressionHandler`:

```
webExpressionVoter.setExpressionHandler(new OAuth2WebSecurityExpressionHandler());
```

You can also try to use `.hasRole( "USER" )` instead of your `.access(...)`.